# value came from a form C# to Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, label

I have a form with C#.

The user fills out the form, by putting his name, and when he clicks on the submit button, confirmation page is displayed with his name in label.

```
<asp:Label ID="name_user" runat="server">Label</asp:Label>
```

I would like add a javascript on head party `[<head>]` when this page (confirmation page) is displayed; like that :

```
<script>
dataLayer = [{
'transactionName': '" toto "'
"}]</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    dataLayer = [{
        'transactionName': '" name_user "'


        "}]</script>
```

How I can get the value of label of `name_user` to put in my script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try simply rendering the page with it there:

```
<script>
    dataLayer = [{
        'transactionName': '<%= name_user.Text %>'
    }];
</script>
```

Or pulling it with jQuery (careful of .NET's control IDs, it prepends a chain of parent control (naming container) names to the final control ID, hence the `$=` usage (ends with)):

```
<script>
    dataLayer = [{
        'transactionName': $('[id$="name_user"]').text();
    }];
</script>
```

Comment: +1. When using first sample don't forget to fix script injections/handing of quotes in the `Text`... For jQuery one make sure to get correct ID (can't remember how/if it is generated for labels).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yep, I definitely agree. This should be a good start at least.

Answer (score -1):

To get the value of a label you must use the function "html".

We also use the ClientID of control if you are using MasterPage

$("#<%=name_user.ClientID%>").html();

Comment: `.html()` does not just return the elements value but returns the inner HTML including any markup of any childnodes. `.value()` gets just the value of the element which is what you would want to use instead in this case.